# Changing what character is sent while pressing shift

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, remapping, keymap, button-remapping

I'd like to change they way my keyboard works.
I want my

> <  and  >

keys changed to

> "  and  "

keys.
Is there a way to change what the a key will send if the shift key is held down.
I'm using both Windows 10 (64-bit) and Arch Linux 4.15.5-1.
As far has hardware platform...I have a PoseidonZ mechanical keyboard hooked up through a USB cable.

Comment: welcome to superuser: It is possible to change the key operations and i am sure this has been answered before on this site somewhere,if not i will, but Hotkeys or autokeys From https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/38554/bind-strings-to-hotkey/38555#38555 or https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=AutoHotkey   may help you.

Comment: There may in fact be useful answers to your question, but we do need to know what operating system and version you're using - a Linux solution wouldn't be appropriate if you're using Windows.

Comment: You neglect to clarity the hardware platform (as well as OS).  PC keyboards generate scancodes, not characters.  The mapping of a scancode to a character is performed by the keyboard driver (i.e. in software).